# Django user register url redirect broken

Tags: django, authentication

My user registration flow has broken. I have the below code in `views.py`, but receive a no user.url attribute error (as included beneath the views code). The user's being created properly and I can navigate to the new user profile page, but the link's broken. I can't find info on the default user URL call.

Can you help?

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'],
                                    password = request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(new_user.url)
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response("registration/register.html", {'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError at /register/
'User' object has no attribute 'url'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/register/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'url'
Exception Location: /home/methuselah/code/django/ssc/dev/ssc/crewcal/views.py in register, line 74
```

Comment: does the line 74 is  return HttpResponseRedirect(new_user.url) ?

Comment: `User` doesn't have a `url` attribute. Why do you think it should?

Comment: @ChrisPratt that looks like he want to route the user to his profile page after logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user object doesn't have a url. If you want to set a url for every user, you'll need to create an additional model with a relation to the user model.

```
class UserAttribute(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    url = models.URLField(verify_exists=False, default="/home/page/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I don't know why you would want to set a unique url for every user though since you can retrieve the user on every request via `request.user` once they're logged in.

So you probably want to just do:

```
return redirect('/profile/')
```

and write another view to handle displaying of the profile. It's tough to answer without more info about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to define a URL for your user, but keep using the user from `django.contrib.auth` and not create a new model, you'll need to add an entry to your [`settings.ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#absolute-url-overrides):

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: '/users/%s/' % u.id
}
```

After you do that, you'll be able to use `user.get_absolute_url()` to redirect the user to `/users/<id>/` after they've signed up.

If you want to add additional profiles to your `User` though, you'll need to create a profile model - at which point it makes sense to link them there, instead of overriding `User`'s get_absolute_url. [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008764/240418) will work better for you when you have a Profile model for your users.

Comment: Wow. I've been developing extensively in Django for almost 3 years and never knew about `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES`. You're never too knowledgeable to not still get schooled ;)